# ASP.NET 4 : Comparing the result set of an object and a string

Tags: asp.net

I am retrieving the contents of a database using a object (its returning only one field) and then comparing it with a string which has been hashed with SHA1 .The code is as follows :

```
protected void Onbutton_click_login(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var dbcontext = new PrepLicensingSolution2010.DAL.LicensingEntities1();
        var user = dbcontext.getloginname(loginName.Text);
        string HashedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Password.Text, "sha1");

        if (user.ToString() == HashedPassword)
        {
            Response.Redirect("faqs.aspx");

        }

        else
        {

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }

    }
```

I put breakpoints and checked the data at each stage of the flow and the data in the object result set and in the string are the same but even then the conditional **if** fails
[image: Breakpoint information]

whats interesting is both the types being compared are of the type string and of the same value,so why is that that the redirect goes to the default.aspx page.

The image contains the data from the breakpoints

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Were the casing exactly the same?

Comment: Yes,if you look at the screenshot they letters,numbers and casing are the same ,I crosschecked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, `user.ToString()` looks to be returning the string `{System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<string>}`. This, of course, does not equal the hashed password.

Your problem is that the result of your `getloginname` call is a sequence of strings containing a single string, not a single string itself. The default implementation of `ToString()` simply returns the class name, and you can see it in the Value column for the "user" row in the screenshot. Changing your conditional statement to the following should fix it:

```
if (user.FirstOrDefault() == HashedPassword)
```